# SQL output the id of inserted new data or output the id if duplicated without insertion

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple table with the following

```
TABLE Color(
    Color_id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Coloring_type [varchar](20) NULL,
    ColorA int NOT NULL,
    ColorB int NULL,
    ColorC int NULL)
```

and I want to execute the following query to insert some data and return the Inserted Color_id to do some stuff with in C#

```
INSERT INTO Color OUTPUT INSERTED.Color_id
VALUES ('solid' ,'red' ,'green' ,'blue')
```

anyway, in fact, insertion like this may make the data duplicated when inserting the same values again so I want to make a query that either insert the data if it is new and output the inserted id or output the id of the same data if they're already inserted to the table, what changes should I make to the query?

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the following one,

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT Color_id  
           FROM Color 
           WHERE Coloring_type = 'solid' AND ColorA = 'red' AND
                 ColorB = 'green' AND ColorC = 'blue')
    BEGIN
        SELECT Color_id  
        FROM Color 
        WHERE Coloring_type = 'solid' AND ColorA = 'red' AND
              ColorB = 'green' AND ColorC = 'blue'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Color OUTPUT INSERTED.Color_id
        VALUES ('solid' ,'red' ,'green' ,'blue')

        SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() --THIL WILL RETURN THE NEWLY ADDED Color_id
    END
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check for existence of a record with an [`EXISTS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) check beforehand and then execute code based on the result.

You can output the id in 2 ways, with an output parameter or the easiest way would be a simple `SELECT` and in C# you would call [`.ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), to return a single value:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1  
           FROM Color 
           WHERE Coloring_type = 'solid' AND ColorA = 'red' AND
                 ColorB = 'green' AND ColorC = 'blue')
    BEGIN
        -- IT EXISTS UPDATE CODE GOES HERE

        -- GET ID
        SELECT ID
           FROM Color 
           WHERE Coloring_type = 'solid' AND ColorA = 'red' AND
                 ColorB = 'green' AND ColorC = 'blue'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- IT DOES NOT EXIST SO INSERT CODE GOES HERE

        -- GET ID USING @@IDENTITY TO GET LAST INSERTED ID
        SELECT @@IDENTITY
    END
```

If doing this in a stored procedure, you would take the values in as parameters and replace the colour values with `@params`:

```
WHERE Coloring_type = @Color_type AND ColorA = @ColorA AND
      ColorB = @ColorB AND ColorC = @ColorC
```

Comment: thanks, but how can I output the Color_id in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this in one statement, unless you use `MERGE()`.  But you can implement the logic.

First, you need to define a duplicate.  Let me guess that you want all four columns to be unique:

```
create unique index idx_color(ColoringType, ColorA, ColorB, ColorC);
```

This will enforce the condition.  Then, you can use exception handling to get what you want:

```
begin try
    INSERT INTO Color(ColoringType, ColorA, ColorB, ColorC)
        OUTPUT INSERTED.Color_id
        VALUES ('solid' ,'red' ,'green' ,'blue')
end try
begin catch
    select @AlreadyInsertedId = Color_id
    from Color
    where ColoringType = 'solid' and colorA = 'red' and colorB = 'green' and colorC = 'blue'
end catch;
```

By the way, it is good practice to always list the columns being inserted in the `insert` statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you set a column as `primary key`, It won't allow duplicate values. So, the real question would be how to get and check the error. You can use try and catch in C# and catch the error using `SqlException e` , like below:

```
catch (SqlException e)
{
   switch (e.Number)
   {
      case 2601:
         // Do something.
         break;
      default:
         throw;
   }
 }
```

If you want to check other error number, go to this [site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number.aspx)..

If there is no error, your data is inserted then you can get the last inserted row using code below:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(col1,col2)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Color_id
VALUES(@col1, @col2);
```

And then pass the value to C# variable:

```
 Int32 newId = (Int32) myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```